# Child route redirecting to home route

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I created a child route to receive the product id and display its details, but the route does not work as it should, and does not display any error messages

[image: Here is a print of the routing module:]

[image: Here is a print of the routing module:]

Running ng serves the application works, but when I go into categories, and choose a certain product to see the details, I'm redirected back to the home page:

[image: Here and the product visualization by categories]

When I press to view product details, I'm redirected to the home page

[image]

Comment: Next time, consider pasting the code as *code* instead of a screen shot so we can more easily copy/paste it into an answer. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

From your route configuration, to get to the detail page your route would need to be:

```
home/categorias/[id]/[id]
```

Because you have the `:id` in the route definition for both the parent and child routes.

Try changing the detail configuration to just `''`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use full path, relative paths are calculated with reference to the path at the time of the component load, so, anything dynamic will be relative to the load time, so your current route will be `''/producto.id` , so it is redirecting to `/home`

If you have access to categories id, use like: (Of course, I'm guessing `categorias.id`)

`routerLink="/home/categorias/{{categorias.id}}/{{producto.id}`}

Other way to do relative stuff, is to use a function, lets say `goToProductDetails()` and call that from the click on button. `<button (click)="goToProductDetails()">`

```
goToProductDetails() {
  this.router.navigate([producto.id], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute });
}
```

You'll need a constructor like:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activeRoute:ActivatedRoute) {}
```